# Link Whatsapp no blogger

Tags: link, whatsapp

É possível criar um atalho (link) no meu blogger que possibilite o usuário clicar e já abrir o Aplicativo do Whatsapp dele com o meu contato de whatsapp e ele possa digitar uma mensagem para mim sem a necessidade dele me adicionar no aplicativo dele?
É possível ou estou querendo demais? hehe

Comment: Existe plugin, e veja https://br.wordpress.org/plugins/whatsapp/ e o exemplo: http://www.amfastech.com/2015/01/whatsapp-sharing-button-for-blogger-wordpress.html

Comment: em breve sera possível compartilhar o link de uma conversa no whatsapp, quem sabe nas próximas semanas. [Noticia](http://www.techtudo.com.br/noticias/noticia/2016/06/whatsapp-beta-permite-convidar-pessoas-para-grupos-com-links.html)

Comment: @renan se for seguir essa pergunta que você marcou, o usuário do celular vai ter que configurar o aplicativo padrão ou "Abrir com..." . Pelo menos no Android aqui é assim.

Comment: Esta [possibilidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/137339/link-whatsapp-no-blogger#) está proibida neste momento